# Как фильтровать подкатегории Opencart при их выводе?

Tags: php, opencart

Есть 2 категории с n-ым кол-ом подкатегорий в каждой. Вывожу в одном месте одну категорию, потом вторую. Вывожу вот так

```
<div class="side_category_wrapper<?php echo $module; ?>">
  <ul class="sc">
    <?php foreach($categories as $category) { 
        for($i=0 ; $i<count($category['children']) ; $i++) {?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']?>" class="sc_item"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Но так я вывожу сразу все подкатегории скопом. Как мне вывести подкатегории, которые относят к конкретной категории?

Answer (score 2):

Есть `$category['category_id']` (категории id) и `$child['category_id']` (подкатегории id), добавил в контроллер `category_id'     => $category['category_id']`:

```
$this->data['categories'][] = array(
            'name'     => $category['name'],
            'children' => $children_data,
            'category_id'     => $category['category_id'], 
            'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
            'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
```

и при помощи костылей все отфильтровал. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю берёте из БД данные?? Можете попробовать nested sets, как раз у Вас получится вывести древовидную структуру, ваших категорий!!!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но хотелось бы на пример реализации посмотреть. Я начинающий...

Comment: Много информации по этому поводу имеет гугл! Вот есть хороший пост на хабре: http://habrahabr.ru/post/153861/   и вот есть библиотека для работы с древовидной структурой: https://github.com/kvf77/DbTree

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки и т. п.